# CSS Centering An Image

Tags: html, css, image

Yes, I know this has been asked countless times and I've read just about every posting I can find but still no solution to my specific issue. On a classified ad site with thumbnail hovers to view the larger image, I need the hovered images to be centered horizontally on the page and vertically within the browser window. So far, when I get it centered horizontally in the browser, the vertical is centered on the page which is often far longer than the window so the images appear either off the screen or at the top edge. If I center it vertically, then it follows the hover horizontally and goes off the screen that way too.

The images, though similar in the HTML example below, are being loaded dynamically and can have varying heights which is part of the problem as I can't simply specify a height. It boils down to the last two CSS blocks with absolute, which causes the vertical centering to work but not the horizontal. Using fixed aligns horizontally but then it's often off the screen vertically. Any ideas?

```
<p><div class="image-container">
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2079.jpg" alt="hpim2079.jpg" width="69" height="52" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2079.jpg" alt="hpim2079.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2080.jpg" alt="hpim2080.jpg" width="69" height="52" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2080.jpg" alt="hpim2080.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2081.jpg" alt="hpim2081.jpg" width="69" height="52" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2081.jpg" alt="hpim2081.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2082.jpg" alt="hpim2082.jpg" width="69" height="52" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2082.jpg" alt="hpim2082.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2083.jpg" alt="hpim2083.jpg" width="69" height="52" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2083.jpg" alt="hpim2083.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2084.jpg" alt="hpim2084.jpg" width="69" height="52" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2084.jpg" alt="hpim2084.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2115.jpg" alt="hpim2115.jpg" width="70" height="53" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2115.jpg" alt="hpim2115.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2116.jpg" alt="hpim2116.jpg" width="70" height="53" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2116.jpg" alt="hpim2116.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
<a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder" ontouchstart=""><img src="/images/classifieds/68/thumbnails/hpim2117.jpg" alt="hpim2117.jpg" width="70" height="53" /><img class="large-image-style" src="/images/classifieds/68/hpim2117.jpg" alt="hpim2117.jpg" width="323" height="244" /></a>
</div>
```

The CSS is fairly straightforward with

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    img.ri { max-width: 90%; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    img.ri { max-height: 90%; }
} 

.image-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 85%;
}

a.mouseover-thumbnail-holder {
    position: relative;
}

.large-image-style {
    position: relative;
    top: auto; bottom: auto; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 10px double #FF0000;
}

a.mouseover-thumbnail-holder .large-image-style {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 50;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: all 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
}

a.mouseover-thumbnail-holder:hover  .large-image-style , a.mouseover-thumbnail-holder:active .large-image-style {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: you are trying to center all these images right?

Comment: Thank you no, all the small thumbnail images are already being centered. I'm trying to center the larger image on hover to the center of the viewable screen. Actually, it doesn't really have to be centered as such but it does need to be completely on the screen when now it is all or partially off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work for you.  Instead of setting `position: relative` on the `a.mouseover-thumbnail-holder` element that encloses the image, let the positioning use the root element as the reference point by setting `position: fixed` on `.large-image-style`.

If you set all the offsets to zero and then use `margin: auto` on the image, it will center itself vertically and horizontally in the view port.

```css
.image-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
a.mouseover-thumbnail-holder .large-image-style {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 10px double #FF0000;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
a.mouseover-thumbnail-holder:hover .large-image-style,
a.mouseover-thumbnail-holder:active .large-image-style {
  opacity: 1;
}
.filler {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="filler">Top Filler...</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/69x52" />
    <img class="large-image-style" src="http://placehold.it/323x244" />
  </a>
  <a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/69x52" />
    <img class="large-image-style" src="http://placehold.it/523x244" />
  </a>
  <a class="mouseover-thumbnail-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/69x52" />
    <img class="large-image-style" src="http://placehold.it/323x444" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="filler">Bottom Filler...</div>
```

Comment: The example works beautifully when run as a snippet but it's not clear to me what the <div class="filler"></div> tags are for. They seem to simply create 500px of whitespace which the page can't have but perhaps I've misunderstood so can you clarify? Above the thumbnails is text of varying height depending upon the length of the item's descriptive text se a height cannot be specified.

Comment: The `.filler` elements where there to show how the images would be placed on a page with scrolling content.  These two `.filler`'s are only for the demo.  I wanted to make sure that the large images appeared in the center of the screen regardless of where the scroll bar was set.

Comment: Didn't see your follow-up until now but funny how the mind works: I snapped awake at 5:30 AM this morning and realized that the filler class was, as you said, just representing the rest of my page and was not part of the answer. Using only the styles (other than filler), it works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @DonP You are very welcome and enjoy the coming holidays and/or the associated time off!

Comment: I hope your holidays are good too. One additional question. Can it be centered horizontally on the page rather than on the container? I'm using the same code on a two-column photo album where centering horizontally with the container causes the left or right edges to be either off the screen or behind the menu.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is use `margin: 0 auto;` but make sure it has a width on the image

Comment: The images are not the same width so it can't be readily done in the CSS but the img src tag is pulling up the width dynamically. Is that what you meant?